# Can't get model relation in artisan custom command Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I created an artisan custom command and in the handle() method i need to get a few info about users.

When i run:

```
handle() {
   $users = User::all();
   foreach($users as $user) {
      $this->line($user->name);
   }
}
```

it works, but i need something like:

```
handle() {
   $users = User::all();
   foreach($users as $user) {
      $this->line($user->summoner->summoner_id);
   }
}
```

And i get Trying to get property of non-object.

If i run the same code above in a controller it works just fine.

Does anyone have an idea?

User model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function summoner() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Summoner');
    }
```

Summoner model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Summoner extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'summoners';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your models and relationships.

Comment: Ok, edited above

Comment: Try to dump `$users` in logs. See what exactly you got in variable. Also this can occur if any user doesn't have phone number

Comment: It sounds like all summoners have a user, but not all users have a summoner. Verify that before you try to print it (`if !empty($user->summoner)`)

Comment: You edited phone number to something else. (summoner->summoner_id). Try logging the object

Answer (score 0):

As @aynber metnioned above, if DB field `user`.`summoner_id` can be set to NULL, then there are users without related `Summoner`.

So you can use `whereHas` method of the QueryBuilder, which will check relationship `summoner` existence:

```
$users = User::whereHas('summoner')->get();
foreach($users as $user) {
  $this->line($user->summoner->summoner_id);
}
```

Or you can check existens of the relationship `summoner` for every selected user, but this approach may select redundant data from DB (if you need all users with non-NULL `summoner_id` field):

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user) {
    if(empty($user->summoner)){
        continue;
    }
    $this->line($user->summoner->summoner_id);  
}
```

You can find more information about `whereHas` method here:

- Laravel 5.4, Querying Relationship Existence: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

---

The only strange thing, that as you said (if I get you right), in non-artisan "regular" controller the same code executes without errors. Possible, it's just a coincidence: may be when you've checked your code in non-CLI (command line input) controller, all users had a summoner.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please mark it as solution and vote up.